# Not able to ping new forward lookup zone

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I am configuring a SharePoint 2013 On-Premise App Catalog.  I created a new forward lookup zone per Microsoft Technet instructions here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx

My domain name is test.local. I created a new primary forward lookup zone using name testapps.local.  I added a new wildcard Alias (CNAME) record using * as the Alias name, so *.testapps.local as the FQDN.  My FQDN for target host is SHAREPOINT2013.test.local, which is where my SharePoint sites are running.

Now when I ping testapps.local I do not receive a response.  I set up per Technet instructions, so not sure what could be the problem.  I configured using test.local administrator account.

Thanks for any help provided...

Comment: can you provide the ping and nslookup outputs as well as screenshots of the testapps.local DNS zone info and CNAME/A records?

Comment: Why would testapps.local respond? That's your DNS zone, that's not your CNAME. Your CNAME is *, so pinging "anything".testapps.local should respond, like joebob.testapps.local, or sharepoint.testapps.local, etc.

Comment: joeqwerty - you are right.  I had misinterpreted the technet publishing.  I am good. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. I added my comment as an answer if you feel inclined to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would testapps.local respond? That's your DNS zone, that's not your CNAME. Your CNAME is *, so pinging "anything".testapps.local should respond, like joebob.testapps.local, or sharepoint.testapps.local, etc.